# How can I sync my prospect list in Pardot with Salesforce Automatically?

Tags: leads, pardot, sync

[image]how can I sync my prospect list in Pardot with Salesforce Automatically?
do I have to enable CRM syncing for each prospect separately? 
is there any way to make this process automatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rickey, there is no need to setup CRM syncing for each record automatically. Once you enable Salesforce CRM, then no need to do separately.

The process is already automatic, there is no need to make it automatic explicitly.

I assume, that you have purchased the licenses from Pardot for your company because there are some issues in training environment of Pardot, and some features (like syncing) is not available in the Training environment.

> **What causes a prospect record to sync from Pardot to the CRM? There are few different syncing prerequisites to consider when it comes to
>   syncing prospect records from Pardot to your CRM.**
>
> For Pardot to sync a prospect with a record in CRM, you must have
>   either an existing CRM record that has a matching email address, OR
>   the prospect must be assigned in Pardot.

Comment: but this process is not automatic in our platform. please tell me where do I have to enable Salesforce CRM? because I checked Admin > Connectors in Pardot and Salesforce connector is verified there
I attached the screen shot as well

Comment: yes, that's all you have to do, if this is verified, then no need to do any thing else. Your records should start getting synced. Please try to make some modification in some record, then check after 5-10 minutes if it got synced or not. I am saying this assuming that you are not using the Training instance of Pardot.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain the problem well. 
I have created a couple of landing pages on Pardot. then we are going to embed them on the website as web to lead forms. 
the functionality I need to apply is that once anyone fills the forms , a prospect will be created in Pardot prospect list then I need to see this prospect in Salesforce as well. ( as  a new lead)
Now the second part doesn't work automatically. 
( I think " Syncing" was not the proper word for this case )

Comment: http://help.pardot.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2128382-prospect-syncing-between-pardot-and-crms-overview you can follow this link. I have updated my answer with some text in the documentation of pardot. Please follow.

Comment: I think the problem is here: 
once a visitor fills the form , a prospect will be created in Pardot but it doesn't assign to a user. so it can't be created on Salesforce as well :(

Comment: Rickey, if my answer helped you to get an idea, please upvote and mark the answer. It will help others in future.

Comment: I'll definitely do that as soon as my problem solves bro

Comment: Hi Nitish I fixed the problem. 
I created a completion action in each custom redirect I had in my Pardot. The action is " Assign to user " 
it works perfectly now 
thank you for your guides